# Location of policy file on Debian

Tags: java, cryptography, debian, jce

I'm working on an application/library, under DebianOS, that requires the presence of certain standard policy files (related to unlimited strength ciphers, 192, 256 bit AES keys).
However, there seems to a problem which I think is related to the application not being able to find these policy files (.jar files).

Sun recommends these files to be located at jre-home/lib/security. However, I do have these files located at this location, still the problem.

Are there any alternate location or path settings for these files?
Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have `jre-home/lib/security` in your classpath?

Comment: No T.J. I have only /lib/ext.

Comment: Could you describe the original problem instead of what you think the problem is? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/137016

Answer (score 1):

run `locate local_policy.jar` in a shell, this should show the folder where the files are located.

Answer (score 0):

Try with 'find':

```
find / -iname "*.jar*"
```

Comment: you are missing the last quote: find / -iname "*.jar*"